# How can I link an outlet from a view controller to an other?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iboutlet

I am working on an app that uses parse so I used the "starter project" as a base and worked from there.

The issue I am facing is that the ViewController is controlling the login screen a well as others such as the tableView and mapView witch I added later.

As this is the case if it would be possible I would link the map  outlet by simply dragging from the code to the map but obviously this is not possible, How could I solve this problem (I understand I may be looking at the problem the wrong way but any help would be appreciated)

here is the code with the map outlet

[image: code]

here is what the layout looks like

[image: this is what the layout looks like]

Answer (score 2):

> The MVC model, Model-View-Controller model, isn't intended to have an action in one view touch the controller of another view.  In InterfaceBuilder, you should only ever be able to attach actions to the controller for that specific view.
>
> In general, if you set the file owner to `ViewController`, then you can only link IBoutlets to that view controller not make to another one.

your map is available in your `MapViewController` not `ViewController`, so you need to give the reference/IBoutlet of map need to assign the `MapViewController`, if you want to implement in `ViewController`, you need to create new one map

Answer (score 0):

No you have to create different file for each controller.
you cant add outlet of all in one controller